# Como diferenciar select's criados dinamicamente pelo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber se é possível identificar elementos criados via JavaScript, de forma que eu consiga distinguir quando for ler esse array gerado.

Especificamente, tenho a opção de gerar elementos `select` e preciso identificar para que possa setar um campo de `obs` e este seja inserido apenas para os objetos selecionados no `select` criado.

Criação dinâmica dos campos

```
$(document).on("click", ".add, .close", function(event) {
        if($(this).hasClass('add'))
        {
            var numero = parseInt($(this).closest('.linha-flex').find('.form-number').html())+1;
            var texto = `<script>   $('.espec').select2(
                                    {minimumInputLength: 3}
                                    );
            </script>
            <div class="linha-flex linha-flex-grow">
                            <div class="form-number">`+numero+`</div>
                            <div class="item-flex">
                                Procedimento
                                <select name="proc[]" class="select-form proc" required style="width: 300px;">`+option_proc+`</select>      
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-flex">
                                Especificação
                                <select name="espec[]" class="select-form espec" multiple="multiple" required style="width: 400px;"><option value=''>Selecione</option></select>        
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-flex">
                                Observação
                                <textarea name="obs[]" class="obs-form" style="width: 400px;"></textarea>       
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-flex acao flex-plus"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg add" title="Adicionar mais"></i></div>
                         </div>`;
            $(this).closest('.linha-flex').after(texto);
            $(this).after("<i class='fa fa-times fa-lg close' title='Remover linha'></i>");
            $(this).remove();
        }
```

Como vincular meu `select` de Especificação ao meu campo de `obs`?

Tentarei exemplificar desculpa se não for claro. Cada `<div class="linha-flex linha-flex-grow">` gera um select e obs. tenho que vincular a obs aos itens do meu select, ate ai tudo certo. porem quando crio novo `<div class="linha-flex linha-flex-grow">` perco o controle sobre o campo obs, devido ao dar submit no meu formulário ele ira transformar tudo em um único array que seria  `name="espec[]"`, sendo assim, me impossibilitando de definir ao certo quais itens selecionados irão receber a obs.porque eu so poderia atribuir a obs ao select criado juntamente a ele. Caso ainda tenha ficado confuso tentarei exemplificar melhor e trazer um print da tela e o código completo.

Comment: Vc quer inserir no campo "obs" os valores selecionados no select? Em que formato? Separados por vírgula? Como vc vai popular o select? Acho que a sua pergunta carece de maiores detalhes.

Comment: Vou editar o post para tentar ser mais claro. desde de já obrigado.

Comment: Vc teria que criar índices nas arrays cada vez que adicionar uma linha,  algo como `name="espec[0]"`, `name="espec[1]"`, `name="espec[2]"` etc...